# Providing an implicit conversion of nil in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Operations involving the plus operator (e.g. string concatenation or arithmetic) would be so much more convenient if Ruby knew that:

```
'a' + nil 
# => 'a'
```

and

```
nil + 'a' 
# => 'a'
```

These statements are unambiguous, but they return errors:

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

and

> NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass

When programming to process databases, e.g. parsing XML and JSON from human-input data, one encounters empty fields all the time, frequently resulting in variables set to nil.

**Specific Example**

Using the JSON gem,

```
json('firstname')
```

will return `nil` if `firstname` is not defined. Then wishing to process the result as a string, I'd normally have to write some logic to handle the case that it is `nil` rather than an empty string. To do this for many fields in a database is very tedious. It would be very convenient if I could handle these by implicitly converting `nil` to a string.

What is the Ruby way to solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot redefine `+` globally. Every class has it's own `+` (or none). So you would have to re-implement all `+`s in order to generally allow `something + nil`.

Comment: which other high level language handles the way you are talking about?

Comment: There's no reason to rely on `nil` as an expected value when parsing XML or JSON or doing anything else for that matter. There will be a better way to do it in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the somewhat negative comments, but I would actually appreciate some practical advice, e.g. the 'better way to do it in Ruby'. I'd be pleased to rewrite the question to make it less opinion-based if that is the problem. I am sure a lot of people have similar frustrations. For example if I am extracting something using the json gem like json['firstname'] and it doesn't exist, nil is returned, which always causes a faff when my program was expecting a string. When processing a lot of fields, it is annoying to write lots of conditionals to handle the possibility that they may be nil.

Comment: For the specific case of `String`, you can easily extend the `NilClass` by a `to_str` method: `class NilClass; def to_str ; ''; end; end`. Then, `nil` can act as string in many cases. To cover `nil + String`, you'd have to add a `+` method to `NilClass`.

Comment: I see you've added a specific example--I made it stand out a bit more and I'm voting to reopen. Are you sure the syntax is accurate in your example?

Comment: If you deal with data that can be `nil`, you could just add a `.to_s` which is defined on many objects (including `nil`, numbers, arrays, ...) It ensures that the returned object is a string-representation of the object. If it already is a string, it's a no-op. `variable.to_s + 'a'` will most probably do the right thing for you.

Comment: You can handle your scenarios as follows `class NilClass; def to_str; ''; end; def +(object); object; end; def coerce(object);[self,object];end;end` I would not recommend using this except in very specific cases as it could cause issues but it will allow you to both perform arithmetic and append strings with `nil`.

Comment: Are you creating the JSON? Why not create it with the keys you need? Also, as Holger mentioned, if you use `to_s` which happens automatically in, for example, Rails views, you don't need to do anything. A third option if you are parsing it into a hash first, you can use `has_key?`.

Comment: edit to my comment by "perform arithmetic" obviously this only handle `+` right now to handle other methods you would have to explicitly state them or you could technically use `def coerce(object);[self.to_i,object];end` but this may again have adverse effects except in very limited cases.

Comment: "To do this for many fields in a database is very tedious" It seems to me that _that_ is your mistake. If you're find that tedious, you're doing it wrong. Nil-checking is easy. The fact that nil will throw a wobbly is good; don't mess with it, check for it. Just catching the exception would do.

Comment: Thanks for the many instructive comments. For my purposes, using the method to_s on all variables that might be nil seems the best solution. In my current project, the problem is analysing bibliographic records in json and xml - I did not generate the data myself, and it comes from different sources, so it is not surprising that it is not perfectly structured. Just using the json / nokogiri modules in the recommended ways produces lots of nils, so it makes sense not to treat nil as an exception, but just brush it aside as an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nil` *does* define *explicit* conversions to `String`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Array`, `Hash`, `Rational` and `Complex`, so you could just do

```
'a' + nil.to_s
nil.to_s + 'a'

1 + nil.to_i
nil.to_i + 1

1.0 + nil.to_f
nil.to_f + 1.0

[] + nil.to_a
nil.to_a + []

{}.merge(nil.to_h)
nil.to_h.merge({})

Rational(1) + nil.to_r
nil.to_r + Rational(1)

Complex(1, 1) + nil.to_c
nil.to_c + Complex(1, 1)
```

It *does not* define *implicit* conversions, because getting a `nil` where you didn't expect it is usually either a bug or bad design. (And if you *do* expect it, then you can test for it or explicitly convert it.)

You *could*, of course, add the necessary operators (`+`, …), implicit conversions (`to_str`, `to_int`, `to_float`, `to_ary`, `to_hash`, …) and numeric coercions (`coerce`) to `NilClass`, but I would consider that a mistake. The implicit conversions are meant to implement an IS-A relationship but saying that "`nil` IS-A `String`" is just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

thats why you should use string-interpolation.

```
nil.to_s == ''

val = nil

"a#{val}" == 'a'
```

Comment: +1 If you are gonna treat it like a string, `to_s` will beat it into a string. And real Strings won't mind.